# VB.NET Service.OnStart() Never Called

Tags: c#, vb.net, service, windows-services

I'm using vb.net in order to create a windows service, where on the **OnStart()** function I'm trying to log a message saying its status, however it seams that the function is not being called. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oi60v7o1wne7fuz/FneishSQLBackupServicev2.zip?dl=0) is the complete project and Below is the target service code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class FneishSQLBackupServicev2

    Dim backupTaken As Boolean = False

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        WriteToFile("Sql automated backup service started")
        Try
            Timer1.Start()
        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteToFile(ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        WriteToFile("Sql automated backup service stopped")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        WriteToFile("timer entered")
        If Date.Now.Hour = My.Settings.AutoBackupTime Then
            If backupTaken = False Then
                backupTaken = True
                TakeBackup()
            End If
        Else
            backupTaken = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub WriteToFile(Message As String)
        Try
            Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\ServiceLog"

            If Directory.Exists(path) = False Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
            End If

            Dim filepath As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() & "\ServiceLog\Log_" & DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString.Replace("/".ToCharArray.GetValue(0), "_".ToCharArray.GetValue(0)) & ".txt"

            Dim log As System.IO.StreamWriter

            If File.Exists(filepath) = False Then
                log = File.CreateText(filepath)
            Else
                log = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filepath, True)
            End If

            Message = Date.Now.ToLocalTime & vbNewLine & Message & vbNewLine
            log.WriteLine(Message)
            log.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Any help please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching and debugging using `EventLog` i found that it was starting successfully however the problem was in the `WriteToFile` functions that was writing to another folder since `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` was returning `"C:\Windows\Temp"` and not `"C:\users\myuser\appdata\local\temp"` when called by the services.